# NavigationDrawer no se cierra

Tags: android, android-layout, navigationview, android-drawerlayout, navigation-drawer

**Navigation componets: BottomNavigationView and navigationDrawer**

Este proyecto se basó en el repositorio de muestras para componentes de arquitectura de Android. Este es el repositorio donde lo saqué: [Repositorio componentes de arquitectura de Android](https://github.com/mackgaru/architecture-components-samples/tree/main/NavigationAdvancedSample)

Lo que hice fue agregar el componente NavigationDrawer.

Encuentro problemas con onBackPressed () y el botón arriba del toolbar cuando doy un click en un item del componente `NavigationDraWer`.

La navegacion funciona bien, pero al intentar volver atras, o al Home, el NavigationDrawer no se cierra, entonces doy click sobre un elemento del BottonNavigation, y desaparece el menu del NavigationDrawer que esta en el Toolbar.

[image: Layout principal]
[image: Click icon Drawer, que esta en el Toolbar]
[image: Se muestra un item del navigationDrawer, cuanso se da click]
[image: Desaparece icon NavigationDrawer, al volver al home]

Aqui tengo un repositorio por si quieres ver a mas detalle: [introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](https://github.com/mackgaru/nBottom_nDrawer)

Activity_main

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private var currentNavController: LiveData<NavController>? = null
    private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private lateinit var drawerLayout: DrawerLayout

    private lateinit var viewModelHome: HomeViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            setupBottomNavigationBar()
        }
        setSupportActionBar(binding.includeMainContent.toolbarActivity)
        drawerLayout = binding.drawerLayout
        val navigationView: NavigationView = binding.navView
        val toogle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, binding.includeMainContent.toolbarActivity, R.string.open_navigation, R.string.close_navigation)
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toogle)
        toogle.syncState()
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)

    }//fin onCreate

    override fun onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState)
        setupBottomNavigationBar()
    }

    private fun setupBottomNavigationBar() {
        val bottomNavigationView = findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.bottom_nav)
        val navGraphIds = listOf(R.navigation.navigation_home, R.navigation.navigation_add, R.navigation.navigation_card, R.navigation.navigation_pay, R.navigation.navigation_config)

        // Setup the bottom navigation view with a list of navigation graphs
         val controller = bottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController(
            navGraphIds = navGraphIds,
            fragmentManager = supportFragmentManager,
            containerId = R.id.nav_host_container,
            intent = intent
        )
        // Whenever the selected controller changes, setup the action bar
        controller.observe(this, Observer { navController ->
            setupActionBarWithNavController(navController)
        })
        currentNavController = controller
        Log.i("controller", "valor es = ${currentNavController!!.value}");
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        Log.i("controller", "support = ${currentNavController?.value?.navigateUp()}");
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_container)
        //return currentNavController?.value?.navigateUp() ?: false
        return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration)  || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }

    @SuppressLint("RtlHardcoded")
    override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        if(item.itemId == R.id.nav_camera){
            Toast.makeText(this , "Camera Click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            //Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.navigationHome).navigate(R.id.action_navigation_home_to_homeDetalleFragment)
            //currentNavController?.value?.navigate(R.id.action_navigation_home_to_homeDetalleFragment)
            if(currentNavController?.value?.currentDestination?.id != R.id.homeDetalleFragment){
                currentNavController?.value?.navigate(R.id.action_navigation_home_to_homeDetalleFragment)
            }
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.LEFT)
        }
        return true
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        if(drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.LEFT)){
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.LEFT)
        }else{
            super.onBackPressed()
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Estás seguro que necesitas 2 tipos de navegación? Normalmente uno es suficiente. Mira [esto](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cbPe9_DKLYw)

Comment: Genial el video, muchas gracias. Mi jefe necesita dos, y me toca obedecer.